# Report Builder 3.0 - SQL to fill in a prompt when the previous one is null

Tags: sql, teradata, reportbuilder3.0

I have 3 prompts in my report : (1) Group Number, (2) State, and (3) Branches.  The user selects the group number (1) and the prompt for State (2) is updated with all of the states the group does business in.  Then the user selects either "null" or one of the states from the state prompt (2).  When they make the state selection, the branches prompt (3) is completed with the sql below:

```
select distinct
bta.stn_stn_id
from ody.bil_tas_areas bta
where 
bta.stpr_id = (select uda.area_id
from ody.usr_dfnd_areas uda
where uda.aty_area_typ = 'tas_a_stpr'
and uda.AREA_DESC = ?)
order by 1
```

This works good when they make any selection but "null".  If they select "null" and want to run the report for all states, I would like to see all of the branches for a group number.  Currently, the 3rd prompt is empty.  I'm not sure how to get all of the branches when "null" is selected.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.......

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to get all of the branches when "null" is selected.

```
select distinct
bta.stn_stn_id
from ody.bil_tas_areas bta
where 
bta.stpr_id = 
(
    select uda.area_id
    from ody.usr_dfnd_areas uda
    where uda.aty_area_typ = 'tas_a_stpr'
    and (uda.AREA_DESC = ? or 'null' = ?)
)
order by 1
```

Comment: .....thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it but I'm getting a Teradata Database 93707) Syntax Error, expected something like ')' between a string or a Unicode character liter and '='.  I'm not sure what it doesn't like but keep searching.  Thanks for your help....

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I was out of the office on Friday.  Thanks...........I no longer get the error but I'm not getting any branches when "null" is selected.  I'll keep looking at it.  Thanks for the help

Comment: The selected value of empty is "null" or "" ?

Comment: There is an actual value in the list that says "null".  So the user can select either a state or the word "null".  If they select "null", then the list of branches should be everything based on the group they selected.  Thanks......

Comment: OK , I got it , i edited my answer again,could you try it again?TKS.

Comment: Thanks.... I just tried and it is still not working.  I looked at this some more and I could use the code below if "Null" is selected to return all of the branches for the group.  I'm not sure how to incorporate it in the sql: select *  from ody.stns
where erac_legacy_group =  '01'        I appreciate your help.

Comment: I was looking at this some more and I'm wondering if I can use a case statement in the Where clause:  something like case ? is null then uda.AREA_DESC IN ? else uda.AREA_DESC = ?.  What I was thinking is that if they select a state then uda.AREA_DESC = ? would pull the branches for the state,  Otherwise, if they select "null" then the in WOULD use all of the states to pull the branches.  Thanks again for helping with this question